# How to force AutoMapper to be very restrict?

Tags: c#, automapper

Here is an example:

```
class Source
{
    public int Value_1 { get; set; }
    public int Value_2 { get; set; }
    public int MissedValue { get; set; }
}

class Destination
{
    public int Value_1 { get; set; }
    public int Value_2 { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Value_1, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.Value_1))
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Value_2, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.Value_2))
        ;
    });

    config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

In the end, i need AssertConfigurationIsValid() to throw an exception when i have missing **Source** fields and not just destination fields.

Also, how to force it to disable any type and naming conversions? Like int -> string, Test.Id -> TestId, etc.
I need it to be as restrict as possible. Or maybe there is a better alternative for my case?

UPDATE_0:
Ok. Found an answer to the first part.
Just need to use

```
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>(AutoMapper.MemberList.Source)
```

It would be great to have support for both validation types alltogether, but it's a good start already.
Now what left is, how to remove all naming conventions and type converters.

Comment: Yes, all that can be done, but indeed, maybe you should find a mapper that works by default that way.

Comment: Well, than i have 2 questions: how to do that using automapper or what is the better alternative?

Comment: About AM, these kind of questions were answered before and some research should provide the answers, but I don't know much about how other mappers work.

Comment: All i could google are things like "how to avoid exception when not all properties are mapped", whereas i need the opposite. The only relevant post i found is from 2014 which uses reflection to query into automapper internals.

Comment: Updated the question. Solution to first part is found.